# How Do I enable PHP to be shown on HTML webpage?

Tags: php, html, webserver

I have been searching on forums and google for hours with no definitive answer other than "Your host may not support PHP". I have dumbed down my PHP page to simply display some text for testing purposes but I am still only getting a blank webpage. I have tried opening it locally into a browser and also through the web server, same result for both. Anyone have an idea as to why this simple PHP wont even show up on the webpage?

```
<?php
echo "Show some text";
?>

also tried:

<html>
<?php
echo "Show some text";
?>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean the actual php code or the echoed result?

Comment: First, is it a PHP file or an HTML file?  Your PHP files must have a .php extension to run (unless the web server is set up to run other files through PHP).  Second, ask your host.

Comment: "opening it locally". Do you have a web server with php enabled?

Comment: So did you check that your host **supports** PHP?

Comment: And I am not sure how to even check for that support...

Answer (score 1):

What is the filename of your file? Is the file extension a .html file, or a .php file? If it's .html, rename it to .php and test with your first test again.;

To check and see if php is supported on your server, create another file titled: `phpinfo.php` and insert the following code in it:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

and save it, and then go to it on your server. You should see the PHP configuration output on that page. If it doesn't work, then you do not have PHP correctly installed on your server.

Comment: I have tried both .html and .php. Same result for both, html is displayed correctly with no problem, but PHP is looked over almost like it is commented out(which it is not)

Comment: Please try the phpinfo() part.

Comment: Considering what each of you have responded with it seems I do not have PHP support from my host. Steph I also tried your phpinfo(); test with the same blank page result. Now I am left with the issue of how I get that support. Thank you all for you timely help.

Comment: No problem. Just out of curiosity, who is your host? Is it shared hosting, or do you have your own dedicated server or virtual server?

Comment: We are hosted by ASI(Advsol). We do have some dedicated servers locally but not for web hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Your file must be ending in .phtml or .php to make PHP work on a HTML page.

index.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Or you can trick your server, Apache and Nginx support this as does IIS. Basically you can have "index.x" or "index.px" - your own custom extension, it is not advisable for obvious reasons. In Apache (your public_html folder) enable this in your .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .ac1d
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .x 
# your custom extension above.
```

Comment: This is going to sound dumb but is there a way to find out who is hosting your server? The company I work at, almost all of their stuff including their AMS is hosted by ASI. But I am not sure if they would be the ones to contact about this unsupported PHP problem

Comment: Never sound dum to me as your learning friend! replace stackoverflow with your employer URL and you can see the host and then find our linux or windows. But try saving as .php or .aspx etc  ".htaccess" files are saved "public_html" folder. Note they do not have an extension

Comment: Turns out our web is hosted by ASI like I thought, I was just hopeing there was an easier way to "enable" PHP to be read on my browser. Looks like I will have to put a ticket in at ASI. Thank you very much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

**To view the source of everything (no processing):**

Most server are setup with a source-viewing format already by changing the file name to use the `.phps` extension. If not, you'd have to create a .htaccess file and temporarily add this line to it:

```
AddType text/plain .php
AddType text/plain .html
```

That should force the files to be displayed as plain text whenever they're accessed. Just remember to remove it later.

Comment: Where would I go about creating this htaccessfile